# Permission denied exception Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I just installed Azure CLI and tried running az --version. Getting permission denied exception for file az.sess

```
OS - Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.19041 Build 19041)
Azure CLI Version Installed (latest) -  2.10.1
```

Tried running Power Shell as an Admin and making sure the CLI installation is not read only

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> az --version
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\_session.py", line 47, in load
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\_session.py", line 65, in save
      File "codecs.py", line 897, in open
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\mmodi\\.azure\\az.sess'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-clkvqii1\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 35, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 848, in get_default_cli
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 65, in __init__
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\_session.py", line 61, in load
      File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-d55550gx\azure\cli\core\_session.py", line 65, in save
  File "codecs.py", line 897, in open
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\<User Name>\\.azure\\az.sess'
```

Comment: Could you try deleting the `az.sess` file and try again?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara I had the same problem, deleting `az.sess` didn't help, but deleting the whole `.azure` directory and logging in again did, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I had to run `az extension add --name azure-devops`
Indeed, as @roman_ka states, after deleting .azure directory (in my case it's in Home folder) it worked.